# curl post: how to send both file and json data in a single request

Tags: python, curl

How to send both file and data in a single curl POST?

Tried something like using -F and -d option together, but it didn't help:

```
curl  -X POST -F 'file=/Users/<uid>/model.tar.gz' http://<uri>/api/v1/modelfiles/ -H 'AUTH-TOKEN:<token>' -d '{"model_id": "<uuid>",
           "filename": "model.tar.gz",
           "framework": "Tensorflow",
           "framework_version": "1.8.0",
           "meta": {}
}'
```

Comment: code formatting

Answer (score 2):

Short version: you can't. That's not how HTTP works. You get to send one blob of data in one POST request, but you are trying to send two (the JSON string and the file).

Longer version: this depends on what your service expects. Is the data from the file supposed to be a part of the JSON? Then you need to preprocess the JSON and put the file data inside, so that you're sending `-d '{"file": "<your file data here>", "filename": ... }'`

Is the file supposed to be a form field called "file", and the JSON data is contents of a field called "json"? Then you can send both using `-F file=@/users/uid/model.tar.gz -F 'json={...}'`. Curl will take care of inlining them into the blob, same as if you had a browser form with two fields.

(note also the `@` sign in front of the filename; you need that, otherwise you are sending the string "/users/uid/model.tar.gz")

Is it something else? Maybe you're supposed to send the data first and the JSON second?